# DbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery error handling

Tags: c#, sql, executenonquery, dbcommand

When I use the DbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() in .net, it will return a scalar.
Is that the only information I will get from this command?
Or is there also an exception, if for example the command is wrong, or there
is a timeout or something else?

Comment: Yes, it will throw on error conditions - this will be detailed in the MSDN pages for the method.

Comment: Set it up in a try...catch...finally block. In the catch block set your exception handling, and close the connection in the finally block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the command times out, or if you have bad sql, ExecuteNonQuery() will throw an exception. The return value from the method is the number of rows effected.

The [docs on DbCommand itself](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbcommand.executenonquery.aspx) are sparse on this, but if you look at some of the [individual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oracleclient.oraclecommand.executenonquery.aspx) [providers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx) for [specific kinds](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.executenonquery.aspx) of [database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.odbc.odbccommand.executenonquery.aspx), it becomes more clear.